# C# Azure MongoDB Linq Near Query

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, azure-cosmosdb

I'm trying to send a query with a location point to Azure Cosmos DB (MongoDB) and get the locations near that point.
I got most of the information from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/azure/cosmos-db/geospatial). And I'm using `Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Spatial;`.

So far, I've tried many solutions of other older posts, and nothing has worked for me.

My class definition:

```
 public class Place : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    [BsonId(IdGenerator = typeof(CombGuidGenerator))]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    Point _location;
    [BsonElement("Location")]
    public Point Location
    {
        get => _location;
        set
        {
            if (_location == value)
                return;

            _location = value;

            HandlePropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    long _addedDate;
    [BsonElement("AddedDate")]
    public long AddedDate
    {
        get => _addedDate;
        set
        {
            if (_addedDate == value)
                return;

            _addedDate = value;

            HandlePropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    void HandlePropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string propertyName = "")
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

Mongo connection:

```
 // APIKeys.Connection string is found in the portal under the "Connection String" blade
                MongoClientSettings settings = MongoClientSettings.FromUrl(
                  new MongoUrl(APIKeys.ConnectionString)
                );

                settings.SslSettings =
                    new SslSettings() { EnabledSslProtocols = SslProtocols.Tls12 };

                // Initialize the client
                var mongoClient = new MongoClient(settings);

                // This will create or get the database
                var db = mongoClient.GetDatabase(dbName);

                // This will create or get the collection
                var collectionSettings = new MongoCollectionSettings { ReadPreference = ReadPreference.Nearest };
                PlacesCollection = db.GetCollection<Place>(collectionName, collectionSettings);
```

Query:

```
var point = new Point(22, -5);
IMongoQueryable<Place> query = PlacesCollection.AsQueryable().Where(p => p.Location.Distance(point) < 30000);

return query.ToList();
```

I get the following error in `return query.ToList()`:

> Unhandled Exception:
>
> System.InvalidOperationException:
>   {document}{Location}.Distance(value(Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Spatial.Point))
>   is not supported.

I don't understand what is not supported neither how to create the correct query for this. Any idea?

Edit:
Call Stack

```
0xE0 in XamFormsMaps.Core.Services.MongoService.GetPlacesNear at C:\Users\Role\source\repos\XamFormsMaps\XamFormsMaps\XamFormsMaps.Core\Services\MongoService.cs:84,13  C#
[External Code] 
0x20 in XamFormsMaps.Core.Services.DatabaseService.GetPlacesNear at C:\Users\Role\source\repos\XamFormsMaps\XamFormsMaps\XamFormsMaps.Core\Services\DatabaseService.cs:20,13    C#
0x7A in XamFormsMaps.Core.ViewModels.MapViewModel.GetPlacesAsync at C:\Users\Role\source\repos\XamFormsMaps\XamFormsMaps\XamFormsMaps.Core\ViewModels\MapViewModel.cs:112,17    C#
0x6D in XamFormsMaps.Core.Pages.MapPage.<-ctor<-ctor>b__0_1>d at C:\Users\Role\source\repos\XamFormsMaps\XamFormsMaps\XamFormsMaps.Core\Pages\MapPage.xaml.cs:27,17 C#
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.
First, I had to change the Location type in the model to:

```
GeoJsonPoint<GeoJson2DGeographicCoordinates> _location;
    [BsonElement("Location")]
    public GeoJsonPoint<GeoJson2DGeographicCoordinates> Location
    {
        get => _location;
        set
        {
            if (_location == value)
                return;

            _location = value;

            HandlePropertyChanged();
        }
    }
```

Then, I used the following query:

```
var geoPoint = new GeoJsonPoint<GeoJson2DGeographicCoordinates>(new GeoJson2DGeographicCoordinates(22, -5));
var query = Builders<Place>.Filter.Near(p => p.Location, geoPoint, 30000);
var result = await PlacesCollection.Find(query).ToListAsync();
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you happen to have the stack trace of the exception you had previous to your solution? I'd like to take a look to see what the problem was.

Comment: I've edited the post and added it. Is it that what you want? That's what the Call Stack window was showing when I got the error.